# Artifacts when blending transparent images with GDI+

Tags: c#, image-processing, gdi+, alphablending

I am working on a drawing program prototype in C#.

I generate a "brush" image that I blend onto a destination image, following the mouse position. It works, but **blending over and  over at the same place generates artifacts**. In particular, transparent pixels on the brush tend to darken the destination image.

Here is the brush and the destination image with artifacts. On the right are the corresponding alpha channels. Last row shows the correct result when I use a flat brush (a semi-transparent disc).

[image: Bug illustrated]

I made a sample program illustrating the issue.

```
public static Bitmap GenerateBrush(double radius, Func<double, double, double> curve)
{
    int npx = (int)Math.Ceiling(radius) * 2 + 1;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(npx, npx, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    for (int ix = 0; ix < npx; ix++) {
        for (int iy = 0; iy < npx; iy++) {
            double fx = 2.0 * ix / (double)(npx - 1) - 1.0;
            double fy = 2.0 * iy / (double)(npx - 1) - 1.0;
            double res = curve(fx, fy);
            bmp.SetPixel(ix, iy, Color.FromArgb((int)(res * 255), 255, 255, 255));
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var bmpDest = new Bitmap(200, 200, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var graphDest = Graphics.FromImage(bmpDest);
    graphDest.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255));

    var bmpSrc = GenerateBrush(40, delegate(double x, double y) {
        double d = Math.Max(1.0 - Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y), 0.0);
        return 0.5 + Math.Sin((d - 0.5) * Math.PI) / 2;
    });
    
    var im = new ImageAttributes();
    im.SetColorMatrix(new ColorMatrix(
        new float[][] {
        new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        new float[] { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
        new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0.3f, 0 },
        new float[] { .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, 1 }
        }
    ));

    int nsteps = 2000;
    for (int i = 0; i < nsteps; i++) {
        var t = i / (float)nsteps;
        var xpos = 60 + (int)(Math.Sin(t*Math.PI*40) * 50);
        var ypos = 60 + (t>0.5 ? 20: -20);
        graphDest.DrawImage(bmpSrc, new Rectangle(xpos, ypos, 100, 100), 0, 0, 100, 100, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, im);
    }

    bmpDest.Save(@"test.png");
}
```

It seems to me like it could be due to a precision issue in the way GDI+ blends transparent images. Any thoughts?

-- Edit

Same problem without color matrix (removing the last argument in DrawImage()):

[image]

-- Edit 2

It seems like no-one has an answer for this - is the question not clear enough ?

Comment: Can't say I understand your question.  But the color matrix has to be part of the problem.  0.3 * 0.3 * 0.3 * ...  = 0.

Comment: Can't say I understand your comment, but the problem remains when I call DrawImage() without ImageAttributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, truncation errors are accumulating. You might try using `PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb` mode for the images, but I'm not sure it will help.

The sure-fire cure is to accumulate the brush stroke into a single-channel image and then use that result as a mask to paint on your canvas.

Comment: Using PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb fixes the problem :-)

And implementing a single-blend stroke is also a good idea, even though the "airbrush" functionality needs to blend over and over. I'll now decide whether or not I can afford switching to floating point precision. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the graphics object's SmoothingMode?  It looks like there might be additional interpolation occurring as you move the brush left to right.

Comment: Yes, I tried all possible values of System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode, it doesn't fix the problem.